# Start from Column 3 Second cell

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Right now the code is working but it is working from the first cell. I want to insert formula from the second cell 
[example][1]

```
    import openpyxl
    import os
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"type_e.xlsx")
    Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('=0')
    for row,cellObj in enumerate(Sheet[3],1):
        cellObj.value='=IF(OR(B{0}="", B{0} ="", B{0} =""),"", IF(OR(B{0} ="", B{0} ="", B{0} ="", B{0}="", B{0} ="", B{0} ="", B{0} =""), "", ""))'.format(row)
```

## simply i had used this and this is working for me for time being

```
           Sheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = 'type'
        #path to save file 
        wb.save(r'Documents\test6.xlsx')


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTSX8.png
```

Comment: can you give an example of the data in your xlsx ?

Comment: yaa suppose we have two columns with column name column 1 and column 2 and i want use this formula in column 3 from cell 2

Comment: add examples in your post please

Comment: added you can have alook

Comment: Do not use images to show data and code, add a proper bloc with data, so people can copy paste and try to help you ;)

Comment: Hey thanks i got solution thanks for your help

Comment: and post your solution to help people coming on your post and having the same problem

Comment: I simply use one line and updated it